# jquery array result in a div

Tags: jquery, arrays

i am trying to show array result in a div. please help

```
var events = [ 
    { Title: "Five K for charity", Date: new Date("03/13/2013"), Time: "11:15" }, 
    { Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("03/25/2013"), Time: "11:15" }, 
    { Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("03/01/2013"), Time: "11:15" }
];

var myArray = [{Title : "one" }, {Title: "two"}, {Title: "three"}];
$(myArray).each(function() {
$(".myarray").text();
});
```

please advice where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

since your myArray is array of object .. so use loop to get array object and `.` operator to get that particular objects value...

try this

```
 var myArray = [{Title : "one" }, {Title: "two"}, {Title: "three"}];
 $.each(myArray,function(i,v) {
   $(".myarray").append(v.Title);
 });
```

Comment: Won't this result in `<div class='myarray'>three</div>`?

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
var myArray = [{Title : "one" }, {Title: "two"}, {Title: "three"}];
$(myArray).each(function() {
    $(".myarray").append(this.Title);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AVCNh/) or [Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AVCNh/2/)

Or Better

```
var myArray = [{Title : "one" }, {Title: "two"}, {Title: "three"}];

$(".myarray").append($.map(myArray, function(v, i){
    return v.Title;
}).join());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AVCNh/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = [{Title : "one" }, {Title: "two"}, {Title: "three"}];

var text = myArray.map(function(o) {
    return '<p>' + o.Title + '</p>';
}).join(' ');

$(".myarray").html(text);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ethagnawl/spQ2q/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [{Title : "one" }, {Title: "two"}, {Title: "three"}];
for(var i in myArray)
{
var title = myArray[i];
alert(title.Title);

}
```